# error: ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer [-fpermissive]

Tags: c, estructuras

```
// Liberías

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 

//Tengo el siguiente struct para nuevo1

struct proveedores { 
    int Codigo; 
    char Nombre [20]; 
    char Razon_Social [30];
    int Numero_Rut;
    int Direccion_Postal;
    int Telefono;
}nuevo1;
```

La función Altas proveedores

```
void ALTAS_proveedores()
{
    printf("\t\t\t*ALTAS DE PROVEEDORES*\n");
    archivo=fopen("arch_proveedores.txt","a");
    while(nuevo1.Codigo!=0)
    {
        printf("Ingrese el Nombre del Proveedor (Para terminar ingrese 0): ");
        scanf("%s", nuevo1.Nombre);
        if(nuevo1.Nombre!=NULL || nuevo1.Nombre != 13) //<- error: ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer [-fpermissive]
        {
            printf("Ingrese el Codigo del Proveedor: ");
            scanf("%d",&nuevo1.Codigo);
            printf("Ingrese el nombre del proveedor");
            scanf("%s", nuevo1.Nombre);
            printf("Ingrese la Razon Social: ");
            scanf("%s", nuevo1.Razon_Social);
            printf("Ingrese Nº RUT: ");
            scanf("%d",&nuevo1.Numero_Rut);
            printf("Ingrese la Direccion Postal: ");
            scanf("%d",&nuevo1.Direccion_Postal);
            printf("Ingrese el Telefono: ");
            scanf("%d",&nuevo1.Telefono);
            fwrite(&nuevo1,sizeof(nuevo1),1,archivo);
        }//cierro if
    }//cierro while
    fclose(archivo);
    printf("Alta/s realizada, pulse una tecla para regresar al menu principal");
    getch();
    main();
}//cierro función ALTA_Proveedores
```

Tira error diciendo

> error: ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer [-fpermissive]

¿Qué puede estar pasando?

Comment: Prueba comparar contra char 13. `if(nuevo1.Nombre!=NULL || nuevo1.Nombre != '13')`

Answer (score 2):

```
if( nuevo1.Nombre != NULL || nuevo1.Nombre != 13 )
```

No puedes comparar un puntero con un entero. El *error* es muy explícito.

En C, **no existe** el tipo *arreglo* al mismo nivel que en otros lenguajes. Cuando tu haces

```
struct proveedores { 
  int Codigo; 
  char Nombre [20]; 
  char Razon_Social [30];
```

`char Nombre` no es un *arreglo*; es **un puntero** al primer *hueco* o *espacio* de los 20 que el compilador ha generado.

Y los punteros solo se pueden comparar *directamente* entre ellos, o con un valor numérico *especial*: el `0` (que es lo que vale `NULL` en realidad).

Por lo tanto, `nuevo1.Nombre != NULL` **es siempre cierto**. Por el simple hecho de que `nuevo1` ya existe.

El error te lo indica porque `NULL` es `0`, y la comparación si es válida. **Pero** 13 **no es `0`**. Es como comparar manzanas y peras.

Supongo que lo que pretendes es comprobar si la cadena se ha leído correctamente. Para ello, has de usar `strlen( )`.

```
if( strlen( nuevo1.Nombre ) ) {
```

Esa función devuelve la longitud en *bytes* de la cadena, y se encuentra declarada en la cabecera `<string.h>`.

**Nota**: Eso que haces al final, volver a llamar a `main( )`, es *curioso*. Cuando la función termina, *retorna* ella solita al punto desde el que se llamó; lo cual indica que la lógica del resto de tu aplicación no termina de estar bien.

Comment: el error se arregla agregandole `const` al arreglo de chars

Comment: @RenatoA. ¿ Podrías ilustrarme al respecto ?

Comment: @RenatoA. si tienes una solución alternativa deberías escribirla como respuesta, para que se pueda votar en función de su valor. Aunque, por lo que dejas ver en tu comentario, te recomiendo que la revises antes.